# What is the right way in python to instantiate an object based on the object name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having trouble finding a pattern for this in python.  I would like to instantiate an object based on its name.  If I have a large number of objects that share the same interface, how can I dynamically create instances of the object based on runtime data (i.e. replace the wonky if/elif statements)?  should I be doing this from the parent object function, a separate function or in the constructor?  Keep in mind I will have a library of 30+ objects that all share the same interface, but I need to determine at runtime based on configuration data which object type I am working with.

```py
class Person(object): 

    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name 

    def getName(self): 
        return self.name 

    def isEmployee(self): 
        return False

    def create(type)
        if type == 'Employee':
            return Employee(self.name)
        elif type == 'Customer':
            return Customer(self.name)
        else:
            return self

class Customer(Person): 

    def isEmployee(self): 
        return False

class Employee(Person): 

    def isEmployee(self): 
        return True

people = [
    { 'name': 'John', 'type': 'Employee' }, 
    { 'name': 'Jane', 'type': 'Employee' }, 
    { 'name': 'Frank', 'type': 'Prospect' },
    { 'name': 'Joyce', 'type': 'Customer' }
]

for person in people:
    p = Person(person['name']).create(person['type'])
    status = "gets" if p.isEmployee() else "does not get"
    print("{} {} paycheck".format(p.getName(), status))
```

Comment: `isEmployee` isn't really necessary; whether or not an instance of a class is an employee is encoded in the class itself: `isinstance(Customer("Bob"), Employee)` returns `False`, `isinstance(Employee("Joe"))` returns `True`. If you want an instance to be considered an employee, make its class inherit (directly or indirectly) from `Employee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it using a dictionary mapping:

```py
type2class = {
    'Employee': Employee,
    'Customer': Customer,
}

for person in people:
    cls = type2class.get(person['type'], Person)
    p = cls(person['name'])
    # do rest
```

Then you don't need the if/else check.

Comment: That is interesting, i wasn't aware of the implicit .get() function on a dictionary object....     So what you are saying is referencing a class name without parens () refers to the class and does not instantiate an object?  is there a name for that, would like to do more reading on it.

Comment: I don't know the name for it, but you can take a look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes. But anyway, yes, that is what is happening. The class name is just a reference to the class object and its associated namespace, and the object instance is not created before you call it with normal function notation.

Comment: If you need a name, I think it's the factory method design pattern. The fundamental way to create an object is to use the class's `__new__` method; `Employee.__new__(Employee, "John")` (the class itself is passed as an argument for, well, reasons. Don't worry about what they are.). However, classes are callable, so that they act as their own factory method: `Employee("John")` basically calls `__new__` for you.

Comment: Thanks!  I found what I was looking for here:  https://realpython.com/factory-method-python/  but the above comments led me to the needed google keyword breadcrumbs to find the right implementation.